# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {...})

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to fetch some example data and display some text in my react native app. This is how the code looks (pretty much taken straight from the tutorial):

```
function getExampleData() {
  return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies[0].title;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return 'Error!';
    });
}

class CenterView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{getExampleData()}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

The response body from the url:

```
{
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977"},
    { "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985"},
    { "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999"},
    { "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010"},
    { "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014"}
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the error message

[image]

If I put `toString()` after the function call, [object Object] is printed out, so I guess it's a matter of turning the object into text before returning. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Comment: JSON.stringify(...)

Comment: Because you are returning a promise (an object!) and not string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A. You are returning a promise object returned from the call to `fetch` method in `getExampleData` and not `Star Wars` as you might be expecting.

B. If you want to render the title(s). It is better that you initiate the call in `componentWillMount` method and then upon arrival in the success callback set the state using `this.setState` method which would run the `render` method.

```
getExampleData() {
  return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
   .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
     return responseJson.movies[0].title;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
     return 'Error!';
   });
}
componentWillMount() {
  getExampleData().then(function (title) {
    this.setState({
      title
    })
  })
}

render() {
  return (
    <Text>{this.state.title}</Text>
  );
}
```